# Returning Objects in C++ (Binary Tree)

Tags: c++, oop, object, pointers, tree

Disclaimer: This is for an assignment. I would like pointers in the right direction (no pun intended) rather than straight code solutions.

I'm attempting to implement a max winner tree (a binary tree in which the node's value is the max of it's children's values, so that the root eventually has the max value of all the bottom leaves). My current `MaxWinnerTree` initializes a tree full of -1s, just as place holders for values to be inserted later on.

**MaxWinnerTree.cpp**

```
#include "MaxWinnerTree.h"

MaxWinnerTree::MaxWinnerTree(int elements)
{   
    int size = 1;
    while (size<elements)
        size = size * 2; //gets closest power of 2 to create full bottom row

    *a = new Node[size];
    for (int i = (2*elements-1); i>0; i--)
    {
        if (i > elements-1) //leaf
        {   
            //Create new nodes with data -1, store pointer to it in array
            *a[i] = (newNode(i,-1,NULL,NULL,NULL));
        }

        else    // not leaf
        {   
            //Create node with data = max of children, store pointer
            *a[i] = newNode(i,-1,a[i*2],a[i*2 +1], NULL); //create
            a[i]->data = max(a[i*2]->data, a[i*2+1]->data); //gets max
            a[i]->right->parent = a[i];
            a[i]->left->parent = a[i];


        }
    }

}

Node MaxWinnerTree::newNode(int key, int data, Node *left, Node *right, Node *parent)
{
    Node *n = new Node;
    key = key;
    data = data;
    left = left;
    right = right;
    parent = parent;

    return *n;
}
```

In my Main, I attempt to create a MaxWinnerTree object to perform actions on (insertion, etc), but I know the way I'm doing it is incorrect. My MaxWinnerTree method doesn't return a value, and the only objects I'm creating are an array and then a linked mess of nodes. As I type this, I'm going to go back and attempt to return a linked list as my tree and go from there, but is this the direction that I should be going in?

**Main.cpp**

```
    int main (){
    bool quit;
    int command, elements, binSize;
    cout<<"Welcome to assignment 6!"<<endl;

    while (!quit)
    {
        cout<<"Choose an option for the test: 1-> First fit, 2-> Best Fit, 3-> Quit"<<endl;
        cin>>command;

        if(command==1)
        {
            cout<<"First Fit!";
            cout<<"Enter number of objects: ";
            cin>>  elements;
            cout<<"\n Enter capacities of bins: ";
            cin>>  binSize;
            cout<<"\n";



MaxWinnerTree* tree = new MaxWinnerTree(elements); //Throws x86 error, also throws error when not decared as a pointer
            tree->insert(7);
                        //Irrelevant rest of non-applicable code
```

In essence, what do I need to do differently to get a tree object that I can operate on after calling my constructor?

Also: I'm shaky on pointers, so if something looks off or bad practice, please let me know.

Comment: What makes you think that you don't have a tree that you can operate on? A constructor's job is to initialize the internals of the object (and allocate resources owned by the object). When you do `MaxWinnerTree* tree = new MaxWinnerTree(elements);` you now have a MaxWinnerTree object. Does it have an `insert` method? Or are you expecting to have access to a Node object rather than the tree?

Comment: My methods after creating the tree will only need to access the root node. 

Creating the object like I did above gives a x86 compilation error. Taking away the pointer and just using MaxWinnerTree tree=... makes the compiler disagree on the return type:  

main.cpp:36: error: invalid conversion from ‘MaxWinnerTree*’ to ‘int’
main.cpp:36: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘MaxWinnerTree::MaxWinnerTree(int)’

Comment: Typically, if you have a class like MaxWinnerTree, the purpose of the class would be to hide the details about the underlying tree. You could do something like have a `getRoot()` method on the tree that returns the root, but now you're exposing internals. If all you need is to construct a tree, you could also just have a free-standing method that constructs a tree and returns the root. Something like `Node* newTree(int elements) { ... make a tree...; return root;}`

Comment: Hm. I don't need a getRoot() method to give the root specifically, but I need to know the root node to traverse from that position, which I just fixed by adding a root pointer to it.                Any idea as to why I'm getting the compilation errors that I am? It won't accept any declaration of my MaxWinnerTree* object, and continues to say that MaxWinnerTree() is returning an int...

Comment: side note: `int size = static_cast<int>(std::pow(2.0, std::ceil(std::log2(elements))));`